# getting wrong output on the second function

Tags: javascript

I have a code in which I have two functions:

- In first function hardcode value is going
- In second function value is going dynamically.

Here is my HTML

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1">
<input type="text" name="txt2" id="txt2">
<input type="text" name="txt3" id="txt3">
<input type="submit" value= "ADD Value" onclick="Addhardcode(1,2,3)">
<input type="submit" value="Add" onclick ="Add()">
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function Addhardcode(a,b,c)
{
    a+b+c;
    alert(a+b+c);
}
function Add()
{
    var x= document.getElementById("txt1")
    var y= document.getElementById("txt2")
    var z= document.getElementById("txt3")
    var a=x.value;
    var b=y.value;
    var c=z.value;

    Addhardcode(a,b,c);
}
//-->
</script>
```

While Clicking on button `ADD Value` I get right answer but, on clicking on button `Add` I am not getting right answer.  If I pass 4 ,5& 6 in the textbox then the output come as 456 in place of 15. What am I doing wrong.    If i have to make an validation on the text boxes that it take only numbers or it cannot be empty . then what can i do for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the concatenated answer is because JavaScript will see the passed arguments as strings. They are being passed as strings because they are pulled from the textbox's value property, which is a string.

This would be the equivalent of doing this:

```
alert('4'+'5'+'6'); // Gives '456'
```

To actually *add* the numbers, you need to convert them to integers first.

```
var a = parseInt(x.value);
var b = parseInt(y.value);
var c = parseInt(z.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you currently call `x.value` it returns as a string, so the `+ operator` will just be concatenating the values.

Use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to parse the values into integers.

```
 var a = parseInt(x.value);
 var b = parseInt(y.value);
 var c = parseInt(z.value);
```

Comment: Or just cast it to an integer. i.e. `var a = +x.value;`

Answer (score 1):

in your code a,b,c are considered as strings and so `+` is just appending them.

you have to convert them into integer like

```
       var a= parseInt(x.value,10);
       var b= parseInt(y.value,10);
       var c= parseInt(z.value,10);
```

before passing on to function `Addhardcode`

Comment: the 10 is good :) avoiding leading zero like `08` value issues